# Enviar mensagem privada phpbb

Tags: delphi

O dia inteiro tentando resolver isso, não dá mais. Eu consigo logar no fórum, ler e apagar mensagens privadas, mas pra enviar o negócio não vai.

Preciso enviar mensagem privada pelo meu software feito em delphi (xe6). O fórum usa phpbb3.

Pelo que analisei, o phpbb envia o seguinte para enviar a mensagem:

```
Post URL: http://site.com/ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&action=post&sid=xxxxx

Post Data:
username_list=
icon=0
subject=assunto
message=texto
address_list[u][2]=to
lastclick=xxxx
status_switch=0
post=Submit
attach_sig=on
creation_time=xxxx
form_token=xxx
```

Os valores xxx devem ser capturados no momento em que for enviar a mensagem, e meu programa captura direitinho esses valores, pois coloquei ele pra salvar a página e eu verificar manualmente se os valores estavam corretos, e estão.

Meu código:

```
procedure Envia();
var
  form_token, cr_time, sid: string;
  pp: TStringList;
begin
  //baixo a pagina para pegar os valores (form_token e etc)
  FPageSource.Text := FCon.Get('http://localhost/ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&u=2

  //form token
  form_token := TRegEx.Match(FPageSource.Text, 'form_token" value="(\w+)"').Groups[1].Value;

  //creation time
  cr_time := TRegEx.Match(FPageSource.Text, 'creation_time" value="(\w+)"').Groups[1].Value;

  //sid
  sid := TRegEx.Match(FPageSource.Text, 'sid=(\w+)').Groups[1].Value;

  //data
  pp := TStringList.Create;
  pp.Add('username_list=');
  pp.Add('icon=0');
  pp.Add('subject=assunto');
  pp.Add('message=mensagem');
  pp.Add(HttpEncode('address_list[u][2]') + '=to');
  pp.Add('lastclick=' + cr_time);
  pp.Add('status_switch=0');
  pp.Add('post=Submit');
  pp.Add('attach_sid=on');
  pp.Add('creation_time=' + cr_time);
  pp.Add('form_token=' + form_token);

  //enviamos
  FPageSource.Text := FCon.Post('http://localhost/ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&action=post&sid=' + sid, pp);

  //O resultado contido em FPageSource é na caixa de entrada das mensagens
  //como se eu NÃO estivesse enviado nada, completamente ignorado.

end;
```

Considerações finais:

- FCon = TIdHttp
- FPageSource = TStringList
- HttpEncode = função da unit HttpApp

Comment: Você não especificou um valor no parâmetro `username_list`. No `address_list[u][2]` tem certeza que é isto mesmo? Segundo a [documentação](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Using_phpBB3%27s_Basic_Functions#1.4.7._Inserting_Posts_and_Private_Messages), deve-se passar um *array* de *arrays*, o primeiro nível deve ter o valor `u` para usuário e/ou `g` para grupo, no PHP seria assim: `'address_list'      => array ('u' => array($user->data['user_id'] => 'to'))`.

Comment: @qmechanik mas o estranho é que pelo navegador o `username_list` não é usado, é deixado em branco. Olha a imagem, enviei a mensagem para o usuário de id 60 usando o Opera (capturei com o Fiddler).

[Imagem](http://s30.postimg.org/mg3bbz5g1/fiddler_phpbb.png)